# Listen to (register to) a specific method of interface without implement all the methods, Java

Tags: java, interface, callback, listener

Interfaces are a good way to simulate callbacks. However, the class that implements an interface must override all the methods of this interface.
Now, I have an interface

```
interface MyInterface {
    void callback1();
    void callback2();
    void callback3();
    ...
    void callback100();
}
```

I want to make a listener that registers only for callback1(). Is there a way to listen to such an event without implementing the whole interface MyInterface ?

Comment: Didn't you think that providing so many callback methods makes the interface bloat ?  You should probably split it into multiple interfaces. Whatever if it makes sense to have some default behavior for them, the default method shown by Sweeper is a good way (+1)

Comment: You are right.  But I have just made it as a theoretical example, and my objective is to register only a specific method among the whole thing, preferably without going through an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alternative to Java 8 `default` method, you can look at the Adapter classes used in Swing listeners. It is a subclass that provides empty body for all methods of the interface. It allows to distinguish cases of you want an explicit definition of all method bodies and the case of you don't want necessarily to have behavior for all of them.

For example :

```
interface MyCallback {
    void callback1();
    void callback2();
    void callback3();
}
```

And Adapter class :

```
public class MyAdapter implements MyCallback {
    public void callback1(){}
    public void callback2(){}
    public void callback3(){}
}
```

Now client classes may use the interface or the adapter class to implement the callback :

```
MyCallBack callback = new MyAdapter(){
        public void callback2(){
           // I implement it only
        }
}
```

Or :

```
MyCallBack callback = new MyCallBack(){
        // I have to implement all
        public void callback1(){
          // ...
        }
        public void callback2(){
          // ...
        }
        public void callback3(){
          // ...
        }
}
```

Comment: That's cool ! Using this logic, I can implement the whole interface in the adapter, and use the adapter when I want to override only specific methods.  Thank you ! :)

Comment: Exactly. It has the benefit to document the intention when you manipulate the one or the other one. You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the methods that don't need to be implemented as `default` and give them an empty body. For example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I i = new A();
        i.f();
    }
}

interface I {
    default void f() {}
    default void g() {}
}

class A implements I {
    @Override
    public void f() { // only implementing "f"
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

If you can't use Java 8 features, you can create a separate interface for each callback:

```
interface Callback1Listener {
    void callback1();
}

interface Callback2Listener {
    void callback2();
}

interface Callback3Listener {
    void callback3();
}

// ...
```

Comment: On Android/Java, when I add *default* to an interface's method, I get the following warning *Default method requires API level 24 (current min is 21) more*

Comment: As alternative you can look at the Adapter classes used in Swing listeners. It is a subclass that provides empty body for all methods of the interface. It allows to distinguish cases of you want an explicit definition of all method bodies and the case where it makes sense to not have behavior for some.

Comment: @MahmoudMasmoudi If you do not wish to raise your API level to 24, then you can try what davidxxx says.

Comment: @MahmoudMasmoudi I have edited to include another alternative.

Comment: Yes indeed that could work. But I wanted to avoid such a solution.  That's why I used a "fictitious" interface with lots of methods, just to tell that, for long interface, it wouldn't be practical to separate each method in a separate interface

Answer (score -1):

This is why it's a good idea to keep interfaces as simple as possible (and preferably use existing interfaces where possible).

Your example of an interface with 100 methods is known in expert circles as "Bad Design". It almost automatically results in bad code.

Comment: This is not a useful answer to the question, only a criticism of the OP's code. It's fine to say that this is a bad design issue, but you should also provide a way to improve the code (just like some comments did).